# Macros print output

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 100

void f(void);


int main(void)
{
f();
#ifdef N
#undef N
#endif

return 0;
}

void f(void){
#if defined(N)
  printf("N is %d\n",N);
#else
  printf("N is undefined\n");
#endif // defined
}
```

Why does this output print `N` is undefined shouldn't it print `N` is 100 because of the function call on `f` before it reaches the undef that removes the value 100?

Comment: the preprocessor does not run as the flow of the program..
If you want to make this use boolean variable not macros

Comment: No; the preprocessor does text processing in sequence of the text in the file, and does it before the compiler proper sees the code.  By the time the compiler sees the body of the function `f`, the macro `N` is undefined.  You can simply use `#undef N`; it does not harm to undefine a macro that isn't defined, so the `#ifdef N` and matching `#endif` are unnecesary.

Comment: Macros are resolved before runtime, at compile/build time.  They are _pre_ -processed.  By the time your program is executed, N is no longer defined.

Comment: Ok but how do i define a macro and how does it works i have searched the web and got no answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessor directives and macros are processed at a very early stage of *compilation*, they have no existence at runtime.

Running your code just through the preprocessor (`cpp -P` -- warning: remove the `#include` first) shows the actual C code that is being compiled.

```
void f(void);
int main(void)
{
f();
return 0;
}
void f(void){
  printf("N is undefined\n");
}
```

As to why this expansion is chosen rather than the alternate message, consider these lines in your source.

```
#ifdef N
#undef N
#endif
```

Regardless of whether it's defined or not initially, it will not be defined after these lines are (pre-)processed.

Comment: If you luser droog gets this message thanks i a things to think about!

Comment: @jonathan The best tutorial I know is by the original author Kernighan http://www.quut.com/c/bwk-tutor.html . It's a little old but still 99% correct, and very short and easy to read. Good luck on your C journey!